# Is it good idea to combine Options FrameWork with Hybrid Core Framework

Tags: theme-options

(This is my first time posting here, so would appreciate if anyone could let me know the best way to post questions).

Until now, I had been using TwentyEleven Theme and adding "Options Framework - http://wptheming.com/options-framework-theme/". It works great and I wish to continue using it.

However I found a better base theme Hybrid Core (http://themehybrid.com/hybrid-core), through which I could better management my development.

I wanted suggestions if its good to combine "Options Framework" & "Hybrid Core" for theme development considering Hybrid already has its own way of adding meta boxes to the Theme Options page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless Options Framework has some gnarly features that knock Hybrid out the water, I would simply... move on ;)

Taking the time to learn a new framework beats the hell out of the idea of merging & then maintaining two - I just think it'd cause more headaches in the long run than it might solve at the beginning.

Comment: Thanks. I guess you are right, will have to spend more time working with Hybrid to understand it better.